# Adding a Tankless Hot Water Heater after a 40 Gallon DHW Tank to extend Hot Water Supply

Tags: water-heater, tankless

I have a 40 gallon tank supplying hot water to 3 tenants (and sometimes their significant others) in 3 bedroom rental home. The 40 gallon does not provide sufficient hot water, so I would like to hook up a electric tankless hot water system before or after my 40 gallon DHW tank to give the hot water supply a little boost. Is before or after better?

Comment: [Related discussions/duplicates](https://www.google.com/search?q=on-demand+water+heater+in+series+with+tank+heater+site:diy.stackexchange.com)

Comment: That won’t work. Either the tankless can heat the water at that flow by itself (don’t need the tank then), or it can’t (it *won’t even turn on* until the tank depletes, and then, weak tea).

Comment: Before would work (it will raise the incoming temperature somewhat, so the tank will have less to raise, so it will recover faster), if you actually have the vast amount of electrcal service free that's required to run an electric tankless. You'll waste less money with an 80 gallon tank, and if you have the power for a tankless, you could consider an 80 gallon *commercial* tank with faster recovery - but depending on climate and how the winter heat is provided, an 80 gallon heat pump water heater might prove worthwhile.

Comment: I'm very skeptical about an electric tankless  WH supplying that much flow.   Not only that, they are notorious energy hogs (albeit in short duration), often requiring 90-120 amps at 240 volts.  That's a huge increase from a typical electric water heater that is usually on a 30 amp 240v circuit. Depending upon other electrical demands, to put in an electric tankless may require a service upgrade and involve the power company. I think your least expensive option (like Ecnerwal said) is just a larger tank type water heater.

Comment: Modern tank type water heaters are very well insulated and energy efficient.   Hate to go against Ecnerwal,  but I'd also stay away from heat pump style water heaters unless you live in warm climate.  They extract heat from the surrounding area, making it colder, so you're up north and the WH is in the garage, your garage could get quite cold!

Comment: This is going to be a strange anecdotal comment, but I have a 3-phase electric tankless water heater that I use to heat the jacket water on a vacuum chamber before opening to atmosphere to prevent condensation. Once, in a pinch, I took it home and used one of the three heating elements so I could get a hot shower while waiting for my gas water heater go be replaced. It was drawing 37A @ 240V and heated the water just fine. Granted, I had the hot water on full with no cold mixed in, but it would run a comfortable temperature for as long as I cared to stay in the shower. 2 cents.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson -- you're right as far as *unitary* HPWHs go, but I'd take a *hard* look at the EcoCute style split-system HPWHs even in a cold climate situation

Comment: Is there a reason you can't go to a bigger/beefier tanked heater? Tankless heaters are *brutal* on electric services....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I agree that we are in a transition period when it comes to water heaters both electric and gas. And YES, they are indeed brutal on on electric services.   My mothers home has, get this, an electric boiler for in-floor heating. It's an old home which heating was originally fired by a very large oil furnace. When heating oil became too expensive, they converted to electric (go figure). Now when I visit her and the electric boiler (125 amp supply) kicks in, I can see a noticeable drop in the lighting. And she has a Square D QO  200 amp panel which I installed a few years go. .

Comment: EcoCute looks interesting, became less interesting when I sorted out the price and "oh yes, installing it yourself rather than paying a few more kilobucks for that voids the already laughable warranty" - at which point I might as well cobble up a CO2 or Ammonia system outside the house with a water exchange loop myself. And @GeorgeAnderson, that's EXACTLY what I meant with "depending on climate and winter heating" - it's one thing if you are in a primary cooling location, or have non-freezing outside air, or gas heat. No disagreement, the heat has to come from somewhere.

Comment: @ScienceGeyser That 37A is very close to the size of British "Electric Showers", which are very low-flow by American standards. Let's crunch the math. 1 GPM = 500 lbs/hr. 240 watts (1A) = 818.4 BTU/hr. Therefore at 1 GPM rate, each amp gives you 1.6 deg F rise.  37A = 60 deg F rise, adequate for a very low-flow shower.

Comment: @Ecnerwal  Re-read your previous comment I finally saw that you mentioned climate "DOH" on my part!.   Next: I don't know what part of the world ScienceGeyser is in, but I have no idea what he's talking about.

Comment: Local tankless heaters can be combined with counterflow heatexchangers, easy to be built, see  " Rob the Plumber" on YouTube. In theory, nearly all energy can be exchanged between incoming and the drain water.

Comment: "40 gallon DHW tank" -- what is "DHW"?

Answer (score 0):

If 3 tenants means 3 persons, there may be options to save money and energy without compromising the comfort - without much installation work or none at all.

Assuming the tank water temperature is set to >= 70 degree Celsius, there is plenty water for 3 persons to shower at the same time, if the shower heads are special types with lowered throughput.
F.e. by mixing more air into the water to make it feel like high throughput.

If the showers have thermostatic faucets, there might be a problem with failing back - flow preventers. Cold water will be pushed into the hot water net, thus the hot water will be pushed back giving the illusion of non sufficient hot water supply.

Back flow preventers are prone to fail in thermostatic faucets.

Another important maintenance point is the heat exchanger unit inside the boiler. There might be a thick layer of limestone that delays the energy transfer. It should be removed with non-metallic tools in order to prevent pit corrosion.

Another option is to decrease the hysteresis of the burner/heater of the tank and to add more isolation to the tank and lines, if there is enough space.
And of course to increase the power of the  burner, e.g. by exchanging the oil burner nozzle (more throughput) or the electric heating element.

For hygienic reasons, the temperature should anyway be kept above 45 degree Celsius in the total hot water net - especially in rented out apartments.